# Why can't I say print $somehash{$var}{fh} "foo"?

Tags: perl

I have a line of code along the lines of:

```
print $somehash{$var}{fh} "foo";
```

The hash contains the filehandle a few levels down. The error is:

```
String found where operator expected at test.pl line 10, near "} "foo""
```

I can fix it by doing this:

```
my $fh = $somehash{$var}{fh};
print $fh "foo";
```

...but is there a one-liner?

Comment: You can "say" anything you want. It is getting it to work that is tricky :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

> Note that if you're storing
>   FILEHANDLEs in an array, **or if you're
>   using any other expression more
>   complex than a scalar variable to
>   retrieve it**, you will have to use a
>   block returning the filehandle value
>   instead: ...

So, in your case, you would use a block like this:

```
print { $somehash{$var}{fh} } "foo";
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and just to make it concrete:
print {$somehash{$var}{fh}} "foo";

Comment: Good point @andy, I edited the answer to include that line of code. Edits are welcome here, give it a go next time.

Answer (score 10):

If you have anything other than a simple scalar as your filehandle, you need to wrap the reference holding the filehandle in braces so Perl knows how to parse the statement:

```
print { $somehash{$var}{fh} } $foo;
```

Part of *Perl Best Practices* says to always wrap filehandles in braces just for this reason, although I don't get that nutty with it.

The syntax is odd because `print` is an indirect method on a filehandle object:

```
method_name Object @arguments;
```

You might have seen this in old-school [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI). Here are two indirect method calls:

```
use CGI;

my $cgi_object = new CGI 'cat=Buster&bird=nightengale';

my $value = param $cgi_object 'bird';

print "Indirect value is $value\n";
```

That almost works fine (see [Schwern's answer about the ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544088/why-cant-i-say-print-somehashvarfh-foo/548221#548221)) as long as the object is in a simple scalar. However, if I put the `$cgi_object` in a hash, I get the same syntax error you got with `print`. I can put the braces around the hash access to make it work out. Continuing with the previous code:

```
my %hash;

$hash{animals}{cgi} = $cgi_object;

# $value = param $hash{animals}{cgi} 'cat';  # syntax error
$value = param { $hash{animals}{cgi} } 'cat';
print "Braced value is $value\n";
```

That's all a bit clunky so just use the arrow notation for everything instead:

```
my $cgi_object = CGI->new( ... );
$cgi_object->param( ... );

$hash{animals}{cgi}->param( ... );
```

You can do the same with filehandles, although you have to use the [IO::Handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) module to make it all work out:

```
use IO::Handle;

STDOUT->print( 'Hello World' );

open my( $fh ), ">", $filename or die ...;
$fh->print( ... );

$hash{animals}{fh} = $fh;

$hash{animals}{fh}->print( ... );
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are all correct.  The reason they don't allow a full expression in there is `print FH LIST` is already pretty weird syntax.  To put anything more complicated in there would introduce a ton of ambiguous syntax.  The block removed that ambiguity.

To see where this madness leads to, consider the horror that is indirect object syntax.

```
foo $bar;  # Is that foo($bar) or $bar->foo()?  Good luck!
```